# How can I Include additional code to then send email via Vba through Gmail?

Tags: vba, excel, email

I have seen similar questions but mine is quite specific let me explain.

I have this code that runs from a button if clicked it prints the active sheet as a pdf to the same pathway as my workbook, this works as it should as the active sheet information changes via a list to present each customer info for each financial period.

Each month i then need to attach each of these pdf files to emails and send to customers which is a long winded process, if i input the email to appear in a cell eg ("E1")  automatically when the customer is selected can i then adapt my code to open an email and send the pdf to that email address?

```
Sub PDFActiveSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder
strFile = Replace(Replace(Range("B1"), "", ""), "", "") _
        & " Period " _
        & Format(Now(), Cells.Range("J1")) _
        & ".pdf"
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

If myFile <> "False" Then
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False


 End If

exitHandler:
     Exit Sub
errHandler:
     MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know about Gmail, but I have already done this with Outlook, so it might be possible with Gmail. Just make sure to import everything you need in your VBA script. You should probably change your question, because right now, "Yes" is a valid answer.

Comment: I am aware it is possible with outlook, although I think there is a setting you need to alter via the Windows control panel to enable it to be possible through Gmail although due to IT restrictions at work I cannot do this.

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of this, best of luck though.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate email sending through Outlook, but it seems like accessing Gmail and sending mail through the web would be a whole different ballpark. Gmail does have an API, which you can get documentation for here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/.

My suggestion is to setup Outlook with your Gmail account and then send through that, which is more likely way easier.

Comment: I see, so if for example I had the Gmail API and set up Outlook through that how would I go about coding it into the existing code?

Comment: Sorry, what I'm saying is setup Outlook with your Gmail account information, and then automate the sending process through Outlook with VBA code. The recipient will see your email as coming from your Gmail address.I've never used Gmail's API so I can't help very much there, but I know it exists for the purpose of sending email programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

From [Ron DeBruins](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm) website I found this and tested successfully.  I did have to enable "All less secure apps" in my gmail settings.  Here's the code in case his site ever goes down.

```
Sub CDO_Mail_Small_Text_2()
    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim Flds As Variant

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "Your gmail address"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "gmail pw"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    .Update
End With

strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 4"

With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    ' Note: The reply address is not working if you use this Gmail example
    ' It will use your Gmail address automatic. But you can add this line
    ' to change the reply address  .ReplyTo = "Reply@something.nl"
    .From = """FROM??"" <Reply@something.nl>"
    .Subject = "Important message"
    .TextBody = strbody
    .Send
End With
```

End Sub